# what value will have property of my object?

Tags: c#

Hi in my opinion property of my object shouold be 2, but after this code, is still 1, why?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass value = new MyClass() { Property = 1 };

        value.Property = value.Property++;
        Console.WriteLine(value.Property);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class MyClass
{
    public int Property;
}
```

in my opinion this should value.Property = value.Property++; first put to value what is in value and the increment property of this object, why id doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What this does is:

1. Evaluate `value.Property` on the right hand side (result is 1) **and remember the result**
2. Increment `value.Property` (now it's equal to 2)
3. Assign the remembered result to `value.Property` (it's now again equal to 1!)

If you change `Property` to a property with an explicit getter and setter and put some debugging code inside the setter, you will see that it does indeed change values 1 -> 2 -> 1.

If you changed `value.Property++` to `++value.Property`, the first two steps would be reversed, so we 'd have:

1. Increment `value.Property` (now it's equal to 2)
2. Evaluate `value.Property` on the right hand side (it's still 2)
3. Assign the result of step 2 to `value.Property` (it's still 2)

Of course, this is unnecessarily complicated and one could even say, wrong. If you want to increment `Property`, all you have to do is this:

```
++value.Property;
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: You were too fast :) I also had another amusing one: "right hand size".

Answer (score 4):

Because `valueProperty++` is the same as the following:

```
int Increment(ref int value)
{
    var temp = value;
    value = value + 1;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value.Property = value.Property++;
```

Here value.Property++ means it assing 1 before incrementing.

Comment: after incrmenting the value.Property is 2 then how it will assingn 1

Answer (score 0):

Because the = operator is lower down the order of operator precedence than increment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx <- shows al the operators and their order of precedence.

The increment gets evaluated first completely. then the returned value from the increment is put through the = operator.