# Add "1" to C# Array each time it's selected?

Tags: c#, arrays

Sorry, I'm having a bit of trouple with this, I've missed out on most of the array lectures so I had to rely on Google to catch up as I need to implement them into this assignment.

So I have two arrays, one to display the name(toppings of a pizza) and another to assign the value of each topping to(can only have a maximum of three per topping, like a single, double or triple topping of cheese). There's probably a way to keep this as one array but I wasn't sure of a way to give a string a value, unless casting works.. I've only done that like once so I'm not sure about it.

Anyways, instead of listing out all 9 toppings, I wanted to make a simple statement that would cater for all of them and replaced the array value with an integer. I don't have it on this computer but it was something like:

```
int i = toppSelection - 1;     //If users presses 1 first topping is selected, but first 
                               //topping in array would be 0

if(toppSelection > 0 && toppSelection <10)
{
   toppAmount[i] = toppAmount[i]++
}
```

Not including the error statements.

I put it all in a while loop so that each time it increments, the toppings name and amount arrays are written out again so it refreshes but the values won't increase. They just stay the same.

Sorry if this is horribly obvious but I'm losing my patience with this now and I'd rather find out how to do it right instead of making a ton of statements for each value of the array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'll need to post your actual code, and possibly a more concise question.  The problem seems to be that your `toppAmount[i]` isn't being updated, but it looks like it is, so the bug is quite possibly elsewhere.

Comment: sure it's defined. It just adds 1 to toppAmount[i]

Comment: @Dan: That's not right, see Marc's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `toppAmount[i]++;` instead of `toppAmount[i] = toppAmount[i]++;`. For an explanation, see Marc's answer or here: [what value will have property of my object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484985/what-value-will-have-property-of-my-object/5485010#5485010)

Comment: Not sure that'll fix his problem if the existing code doesn't work already.

Comment: @Dan: It's something else completely, because his line always overrides the incremented value with the old one. See Marc's explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the line:

```
toppAmount[i] = toppAmount[i]++;
```

this:

- reads the value of `toppAmount[i]`, and since it is **post increment** the "value" here is the ***old*** value
- increments `toppAmount[i]`
- assigns the ***old*** value to `toppAmount[i]`, undoing all your work

You just want:

```
toppAmount[i]++;
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, it still won't increment.. ahh. Maybe there's a problem with something prior to that? I'll try and copy the code from my laptop soon, but I was hoping I'd get away with it. College net is awfully slow unless you use the desktops in the computer labs.

Comment: Interesting!  In C++, you'd get the incremented value (`i = i++` *does* increment `i`).  You learn something new every day ;-)  I guess it's a side-effect of C++ considering an assignment as an expression.

Comment: @Dan - are you sure that is actually a defined behaviour? In C# it *is* defined (and results in the original value), but I wouldn't be at all surprised if that wasn't strictly defined in C++

Comment: No clue whether it's strictly defined or not, I just plugged it into VS and tested... so, strictly speaking: with the VS C++ compiler, you'd get the incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void ToppingMenu()
{
    int toppSelection = 0;
    while (toppSelection != 999)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Create Pizza Menu");

        string[] toppName = new string[10] { "Cheese ", "Tomato ", "Mushrooms ", "Green Pepper ", "Black Olives ", "Onions ", "Pepperoni ", "Chicken ", "Tuna ", "End Custom Pizza Creation - Previous Menu" };
        int[] toppAmount = new int[9] { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        Console.WriteLine("{0}                   {1}", toppName[0], toppAmount[0]);    //Cheese
        Console.WriteLine("{0}                   {1}", toppName[1], toppAmount[1]);    //Tomato
        Console.WriteLine("{0}                {1}", toppName[2], toppAmount[2]);       //Mushrooms
        Console.WriteLine("{0}             {1}", toppName[3], toppAmount[3]);          //Green Pepper
        Console.WriteLine("{0}             {1}", toppName[4], toppAmount[4]);          //Black Olives
        Console.WriteLine("{0}                   {1}", toppName[5], toppAmount[5]);    //Onions
        Console.WriteLine("{0}                {1}", toppName[6], toppAmount[6]);       //Pepperonni
        Console.WriteLine("{0}                  {1}", toppName[7], toppAmount[7]);     //Chicken
        Console.WriteLine("{0}                     {1}", toppName[8], toppAmount[8]);  //Tuna
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n{0}           ", toppName[9]);                        //Exit to previous menu option

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nTo finish order, please enter '999'");
        Console.Write("\n\nSelection: ");

        toppSelection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int i = toppSelection - 1;                                  //i is assigned same value as number entered -1,
                                                                    //i-1 fixes the 1-off fault, where 0 = first topping in array but 1 = first topping by user entry
        if (toppAmount[i] > 2)                 //
        {
            Console.Write("Error, invalid amount");
        }
        else if (toppSelection > 0 && toppSelection < 10)
        {
            toppAmount[i]++;
        }
```

Got all of my other methods done now so I have come back to this. I'm expecting I have made an embarrassingly basic mistake(or many!) but here it is, sorry the late hour. Some of my coding probably seems a bit primitive but this is what we'd be expected to do  from what we've been taught this year. No sense in replacing things with something I haven't covered yet so if just worry about the logic/syntax of the values I want to increment =]

toppName = Array of named toppings
toppAmount = Array of topping values, two start at one because they're default choices

toppSelection = User input and defines which topping is selected

Thanks again for the help guys, sorry to trouble you.

Comment: Solved the problem. I just changed the amount array to a global variable and it began to increment. Each time I the method was recalled the values must have reset. 

Thanks for all your help regardless guys =]